# Why the first hop of a route is not indicated despite being accessible?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

**Summary:**

I can ping the gateway but a traceroute via this gateway does not show it as the first hop, why?

```
root@tor ~# traceroute 1.1.1.1  -nn
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
```

**Details:**

I am debugging the connectivity in a container which is firewalled to allow traffic only though a VPN. This is not visible from the perspective of the container (the firewalling is on the host of the container).

My problem is that the connectivity sometimes fails and I suspect the VPN provider to be at fault. The typical symptom is a hanging

```
root@tor ~# ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

In order to investigate, I checked the route a packet to `1.1.1.1` would take

```
root@tor ~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: host0@if59: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:fa:2e:69:dd:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.200.0.3/24 brd 10.200.0.255 scope global host0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d4fa:2eff:fe69:dd30/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 10.29.10.6 peer 10.29.10.5/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8d09:3f0d:9e5f:8298/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@tor ~# ip route get 1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1 via 10.29.10.5 dev tun0 src 10.29.10.6 uid 0
    cache

root@tor ~# ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.29.10.5 dev tun0
default via 10.200.0.254 dev host0 proto dhcp src 10.200.0.3 metric 1024
10.1.1.0/24 via 10.200.0.254 dev host0 proto static onlink
10.29.10.1 via 10.29.10.5 dev tun0
10.29.10.5 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.29.10.6
10.30.1.0/24 via 10.200.0.254 dev host0 proto static onlink
10.100.10.0/24 via 10.200.0.254 dev host0 proto static onlink
10.100.20.0/24 via 10.200.0.254 dev host0 proto static onlink
10.200.0.0/24 dev host0 proto kernel scope link src 10.200.0.3
10.200.0.254 dev host0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.200.0.3 metric 1024
46.166.138.140 via 10.200.0.254 dev host0
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.29.10.5 dev tun0
```

At the same time, a traceroute does not recognize the first hop:

```
root@tor ~# traceroute 1.1.1.1  -nn
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
```

**Why is it so? I expected the trace to stop after the gateway.**

Note: restarting the VPN fixes the issue so I am pretty sure it is the culprit.

EDIT: when restarted (or running correctly) the route is traceable:

```
root@tor /e/s/system# traceroute 1.1.1.1  -nn
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.38.10.1  17.959 ms  18.217 ms  18.230 ms
 2  46.166.138.190  18.393 ms * *
(...)
```

Comment: traceroute relies on “TTL expired” ICMP messages. Some router don’t send these, sometimes due to misconfiguration.

Comment: @DanielB: this is correct - but the route is traceable once the VPN is up (I updated my question with this)

Comment: Use `wireshark`/`tcpdump` on the VPN interface to debug. If the only difference between working/not working is that you don't get "TTL expired" replies, then yes, then VPN provider is at fault, and you can't do anything about it.

Comment: @WoJ - try `traceroute -I 1.1.1.1` and see if that works.